authentication from scartch in rails
Hi i am learning rails from the Odin project and i am creating a simple authentication without using devise .  the course doesn't really give enough info to help beginners finish that project
so, Here is the part that i don't understand. the login method
class RegistrationController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(registration_params)
    if @user.save
      login @user
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render :new

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  private
    
  def login(user)
    Current.user= user
    reset_session
    session[:user_id] = user.id
  end

I don't understand what Current.user = user does
I can't find anything for the "Current" object and is user a method in it?
The source code here seems hard for me to understand https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/CurrentAttributes.html

The class Current has a methods user= and user (i.e. setter and getter for the @user attribute) if you define it that way. You can define it to have this in the simplest way like this:
class Current < ActiveSupport::CurrentAttributes
  attribute :user
end

That is sufficient, but if you would like to include other methods, like account, request_id etc, you can add them too.
In the simplest implementation, having assigned Current.user = user, then you can access this attribute in models, helpers and views for the duration of the request.

sorry for asking more about such an easy question, why don't i get any output when i type this in my index.html.erb <%= "Current user: #{Current.user}" %>. i thought it will output something like this #User:0x00007fab31ac69d8

after the login, there is a redirect, which triggers a new request from the browser. The value of Current.user is not persisted across requests, only within a request.

Current is like global state during some process
class Current < ActiveSupport::CurrentAttributes
  attribute :user
end

So if you call Current.user = user in some controller then somewhere later in view, for example, you can read Current.user to have variable that was saved before

so i use Current.user instead of passing instance variables from the controller

something like this

sorry but i don't get it if current.user can be called anywhere why don't i get any output here <%= "Current user: #{Current.user}" %>

also why don't i just use an instance variable instead @myvar in a private method and make it a helper method so i can use it in view. sorry i am just new to rails

Current is a singleton of ActiveSupport::CurrentAttributes.

Abstract super class that provides a thread-isolated attributes
singleton, which resets automatically before and after each request.
This allows you to keep all the per-request attributes easily
available to the whole system.

So it's basically like a glorified global.
ActiveSupport::CurrentAttributes is one of the more controversial additions to Rails and I generally think your authentication system would be better if you avoid it and instead think about what parts of the application should be aware of the current user.
Here it's also completely pointless as the controller just redirects right after you sign the and you'll never actually use it in the same request.
